# VS Code drops leading zero in picklist metadata values

Tags: picklist, metadata, vs-code

I'm having picklist metadata problems with VS code and a regular sandbox (not a scratch org).  I'm using source format with the sandbox.  I have a picklist where some values have leading zeros, e.g. "01", "02", etc.  When I retrieve the field's metadata, the leading zero has been dropped in both the label and full name.  Example: instead of "01" I get "1":

```
<fullName>1</fullName>
<default>false</default>
<label>1</label>
```

I need to commit and deploy this metadata with the leading zero.  This is a regular picklist, it doesn't use a Global Value Set.

I searched the SF extension github but didn't find any issues.

Has anyone run into this?  I tried disabling the RedHat XML extension but it didn't solve anything.

**UPDATE** I tried a different computer that had earlier versions of VS Code and SF Extension Pack, and it worked correctly.  Then I updated VS Code and SF Extensions to the latest version and it dropped the leading zeros also.  I've opened an issue on the SF extensions github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with a new experimental Preference Setting in the SF Extension Pack for VS code.  The fix is to disable this setting:

1. File > Preferences > Settings (Windows or Linux) or Code > Preferences > Settings (Mac)
2. Search for salesforcedx-vscode-core and uncheck Experimental: Deploy Retrieve

See this [github issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/3138).